# Memory Eror : Multiplying two matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, tf-idf

I am stuck with the following issue: I have a very large sparse matrix which contains 13M+ nnz elements and a vector which size is approx. 99k+. The thing is when I iteratively multiply and save it in a crs matrix it works but takes 3 hours to complete. Thus I convert the vector into a diagonal matrix so I can directly multiply the two.However I am taking memory error all the time (8 GB ram with 64 bit operating system). Here is my code :

```
GG=list(chain.from_iterable(list(IDFMatrix.data)))
dictDocFreqMat=TermFreq.dot(GG) #memory Error
for i in range(counter):
    TermFreqCsr[i,:]=TermFreq[i].multiply(GG) # Takes 3 hours 
    progessbar.update(1)
progessbar.close()
```

Any advice about the issue?

Comment: The reason is simple: you ran out of RAM. You either get more or optimize your program to use less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all edits and recommendations. I have solved my problem by re-installing python. It was (sadly I didnt notice before) 32bit. After installing 64 version memory error issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

You ran out of memory. What you can do is turn to pyspark for data this big. Spark has a block matrix  data type and you can use it to multiply two matrices.

```
a_mat = tfidf_vect.fit_transform([..., ..., ...])
b_mat = tfidf_vect.fit_transform([..., ..., ...])

a_block_mat = create_block_matrix(a_mat)
b_block_mat_tr = create_block_matrix(b_mat.transpose())
cosimilarities = a_block_mat.multiply(b_block_mat_tr)
```

Source : https://labs.yodas.com/large-scale-matrix-multiplication-with-pyspark-or-how-to-match-two-large-datasets-of-company-1be4b1b2871e (Third attempt)